# Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

Tags: xcode

Are there any other solutions other than setting the code signing entity to `iPhone Developer` ? The reason why I can't do that is because of Fastlane issues (profiles are currently specified).

Where do I set it to so that the uitest bundle will be manual instead of automatic?